# jQuery: append html block to closest clicked link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to generate a html code block when I click on a link. I have the same link "**Reply**" several times on the page. But I want to generate the code under the clicked link. I tried using **$(this)** but it did not work. Thanks for your help! If there is a better solution, please let me know. Also for reference, I am trying to create a reply textarea just like on Youtube when you click on the reply link it opens a textarea for the user to input text.

The sample code is available here [**Sample Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/vchouhan/dV7t5/2/)

Comment: You have the library set to mootools in your fiddle code.  Also, this looks wrong. $(".grid_11 underVideo") since underVideo is a class.

Comment: Your code doesn't work even with `jQuery` set on jsFiddle. But I think `closest()` is what you're looking for. Also why `<hr>`?.

Comment: I noticed that you tried to use `".grid_11 underVideo"` as a selector. That selector is looking for a  `.grid11` class with an `underVideo` tag as a child. The selector I think you are after would be `".grid_11.underVideo"`

Comment: @elclanrs the hr tag is just a temporary fix to see a division between the 2 rows. I am going to add spacer.gif. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: @Gregg I apologize I did not realize that i forgot to change the library set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/dV7t5/5/)

```
$(".reply").one('click', function (event) {
    var html = "<div class='alpha grid_11 underVideo'><ul><li><textarea class='roundedCorners textAreaLabel' rows='4' cols='100' wrap='off' placeholder='Respond to this video...' name='CommentTextArea'></textarea></li></ul></div>";
    $(this).parent().after(html);
    return false;
});
```

Since there was a class `.reply` on the target element, I used that instead of `.normalText a:last-child`.

Instead of binding 'click' to the element, `.one` is used. Using `.one` will only fire once which will prevent adding multiple textareas.

`$(this)` refers to the element clicked which in this case is the `a.reply` element. Using `.parent()` will travel up the DOM and select the parent which is a `span`. And of course, `.after(html)` inserts the html after the `span`.

`return false;` does both `.preventDefault();` `.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Thanks alpaca! This works! and thank you for explaining how you worked the solution! I had another question? Can I add functionality to the newly generated textarea?

Answer (score 0):

try this for your JS:

```
$(".normalText a:last-child").bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().before("<div class='alpha grid_11 underVideo'><ul><li><textarea class='roundedCorners textAreaLabel' rows='4' cols='100' wrap='off' placeholder='Respond to this video...' name='CommentTextArea'></textarea></li></ul></div>");    
    });    ​
```

`$(this)` will return the current element, `.parent()` will move up one level in the DOM so you can append your html (in the case of `.before` it's prepend)

Comment: Is there anyways I can add more functionality to the div which is generated. I mean I want to add focus and blur functionality to the new text field which is generated.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Highly appreciate you taking the time off to revert back to my query. Your solution works but the solution suggested by @alpaca is more refined.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Might even consider using data() instead of the href, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/C3NNt/